# Sending Email asynchronously in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, asynchronous

I was wondering if theres a way to send email asynchronously in asp.net c#. I've used the following code to send the emails:

```
 if (checkObavijest.Checked)
            {
                List<hsp_Kupci_Newsletter_Result> lista = ServisnaKlasa.KupciNewsletter();
                for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++)
                {
                    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

                    mail.From = new MailAddress("*******");
                    mail.To.Add(lista[i].Email);
                    mail.Subject = "Subject";
                    mail.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                    mail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
                    mail.Body = "Some message";
                    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
                    Object state = mail;
                    smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("****@gmail.com", "****");
                    smtpClient.Port = 587;
                    smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtpClient.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(smtpClient_SendCompleted);
                    try
                    {
                        smtpClient.SendAsync(mail, state);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }

 void smtpClient_SendCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            MailMessage mail = e.UserState as MailMessage;

            if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error != null)
            {
                string poruka = "Emailovi poslani!";
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + poruka + "');", true);
            }
        }
```

But when I tick the option for sending emails, the page loads like 40 seconds, then after 40 seconds emails are sent then. As you can see I'm pulling out like 20-30 emails currently out of my DB. I thought this was the correct way to send mails asynchronously, but apparently its not... How can I push the email sending to another thread so it doesn't affects the user who is using this page? Can someone help me out with this ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is mentioned here on the [MSDN documentation on SmtpClient.SendAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h(v=vs.110).aspx)

> After calling SendAsync, you must wait for the e-mail transmission to
>   complete before attempting to send another e-mail message using Send
>   or SendAsync.

You could call `SendAsync` using `ThreadPool` thru a wrapped method call. This would give you something like a fire-and-forget scenario.

Something like this:

```
public void SendViaThread(System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message) {
    try {
        System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(SendViaAsync, message);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw;
    }
}

private void SendViaAsync(object stateObject) {
    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
    System.Net.Mail.MmailMessage message = (MmailMessage)stateObject;
    ...
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("...");
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.Host = "...";
    ...
    smtp.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(smtpClient_SendCompleted);
    ...
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

And you would call `SendViaThread(mail)` in your code. So, your loop now becomes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++) {
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.From = new MailAddress("...");
    mail.To.Add(lista[i].Email);
    mail.Subject = "...";
    ...
    mail.Body = "...";
    SendViaThread(mail);
 }
```

Comment: Ill try it out, but why  did u declare sendviathread function as bool, why not void?

Comment: Oh.. that is part of my code in one of my projects.. I am doing some more work and returning a bool to indicate problems. You don't really need that. Thanks for pointing out, I will remove that part.

Comment: Can you be more specific how can I build this into my existing code? I m not really sure what am I supposed to do here...

Comment: @perkes456: I have made the answer clearer. All you to do is to remove the `smtpclient` related code in your existing loop and just call `SendViaThread(mail)` instead of `smtpClient.SendAsync(mail, state)`

Comment: Should I do it like this:

Object state = mail;
try
{
SendViaAsync(state);
SendViaThread(mail);
}

or just
try
{
SendViaThread(mail);
}
Which one?

Comment: Just call `SendViaThread(mail)`. Am updating the answer to include your side of the code as well.

Comment: @perkes456: Added your code to the answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: It works perfect now, ty so much ! :) P.S. When I used the first code above, I was getting an error "out of memory", do you think its gonna appear again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65428/discussion-between-perkes456-and-abhitalks).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to not have your main thread waiting, try tossing it in a Task.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew( () => {
  // do mail stuff here
});
```

Be aware, though that each time you spawn a task, it'll spawn a new (or re-use) a thread that your system has made.   If you're firing off 30 e-mails, you have the potential of firing off a *lot* of threads (the system has a programmable cap, too).     `Task.Factory.StartNew` is a very simple way to do a fire-and-forget process.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
(in this example, the code is also keeping a collection of `Tasks`, which is nice if you care to manage them -- but in reality, you only need the `Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{` bit if you want to fire-and-forget.  Just be careful because you don't want to have orphaned threads pegging your memory usage.

Comment: Is there any way I can dispose of those threads once they're finished with sending mails...

Comment: Not really, you can let the system handle freeing up those tasks.  Once they're done, they're done.    -- see this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/25/10287435.aspx

As an aside, you can also use Task.Run (instead of .StartNew) -- look into that as well.  If you *want* to be anal about tracking your tasks, you could add them to a collection like the example had listed - or wrap them in `using` when launching (using cleans itself up and its locals).   But I'd recommend just letting .NET handle cleanup and not fret about it.

Comment: In the past, I've added spawned threads to a collection so that I can keep an eye on their process, what they're doing, and be able to remove them if needed (multithreading is a fun [not] world to go down).   Task.Run/StartNew makes it easy to get your feet wet without having to worry so much about thread states, race conditions, etc.    Perfect for your fire-and-forget scenario here.

Comment: I was getting an error "Out of memory" using the first code I posted in the question, could that be the cause of the error?